# Handling IndexError exceptions with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning Python and I have this exercise where you have to handle exceptions. The goal of this one is to throw an exception when the value of the given key is not in the range of the list "self.data".

This is what I'm supposed to enter in my function to test it:

```
v = Vecteur(-9, -6, 2, 3, -2)
v[-1]
```

Now I'm supposed to get an *IndexError*

```
class Vecteur:
    def __init__(self, *valeurs):
        self.data = list(valeurs)

    def __getitem__(self,key):    

        try:
            erreur = self.data[key]
        except IndexError:
            print('indice invalide pour ce vecteur')

        return self.data[key] 

    def __setitem__(self,key,item):
        self.data[key] = item
```

Can one of you enlighten me on the subject?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you unpack `*valeurs` then pack it again with `list(valeurs)`?...Just pass  it directly to `self.data`

Comment: And What's exactly your issue here?

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast, I'll edit my post to clarify this :)

Comment: Remember negative indexing is valid in Python, so your code works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that you're catching the IndexError, and then `print`ing, and letting execution fall through.

I'd do this instead:

```
class Vecteur:
    def __init__(self, *valeurs):
        self.data = list(valeurs)

    def __getitem__(self,key):    

        try:
           return self.data[key]
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError('indice invalide pour ce vecteur')

    def __setitem__(self,key,item):
        self.data[key] = item
```

By the way, `-1` is a valid index. Therefore, you might want to change your `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key < 0:
        raise ValueError("Index has to be greater than 0")
    # the rest of your __getitem__ here
```